# Tomcat 6 & PHP with enctype - No input data returned

Tags: php, file, tomcat, upload, enctype

I have this problem when I'm using PHP5/HTML on Apache-Tomcat6.
Here's an example for one of the forms I use in my site:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="hello.php" >


    <label>Title* :</label> 
    <input type="text" name="title" /> 




    <label>Image:</label>
    <input type="file" name="image" /><br />



<input type="submit" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

Whenever I add the 'enctype' attribute to any form; neither the $_FILES['image'] is returned nor the $_POST variables. As long as the 'enctype' is not there, everything (except for the file input of course) works as expected. Can any one guide me please?

Comment: you need to change the method from `get` to `post` first of all... otherwise youll never have anything in `$_POST`

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to `post` data with a method of `get` on your form.

In `test.html`:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="hello.php" >
    <label>Title* :</label> 
    <input type="text" name="title" /> 

    <label>Image:</label>
    <input type="file" name="image" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

In `hello.php`:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
```

Depending upon your server configuration, this will combine `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_COOKIE`, but you'll still want to `post` with file inputs.

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

Comment: Sorry guys, when the POST didn't work I tried GEt and then I forgot to modifiy it before asking here. I used post method in first place. And I had the same problem.

Comment: Either print_r($_POST); and print_r($_REQUEST);
return Array ( ) !

Comment: I just tried this on localhost, the exact code from my answer: The result was: `Array ( [title] => test ) Array ( [image] => Array ( [name] => delete confirm.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\phpD76F.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 4629 ) )` You must have something else interfering.

Comment: Then it's not a code problem. What other could cause that? Do I have to activate an extension or something like that?

Comment: Check your `phpinfo()` for the directives that allow uploading, and the file's size, and ensure that your tmp directory has write permissions.

Comment: file_uploads = On; upload_max_filesize = 10M; upload_tmp_dir = D:\khafier; And this directory has all the rights and permissions!

Comment: that's me being stumped, then.

Comment: Damn, I really need this :(. Anyway, thanks MetalFrog; you did a big effort ;)